# sudo: passenger-memory-stats: command not found

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger

This is my first time setting up a server, and I've hit snag while following the Phusion Passenger tutorial described [here](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rubygems_generic_install). The instructions ask me to run this command:

```
passenger-memory-stats
```

Which results in this error:

```
*** WARNING: Please run this tool as root. Otherwise the private dirty RSS of processes cannot be determined.
```

But when I run:

```
sudo passenger-memory-stats
```

I get this error:

```
sudo: passenger-memory-stats: command not found
```

I followed advice elsewhere and used `which` to get the full path to passenger-memory-stats. Yet that leads to this:

```
> sudo /home/timothythehuman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/passenger-memory-stats

/usr/bin/env: ruby_noexec_wrapper: No such file or directory
```

Any other approaches to getting this work? Or an idea of why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo`, by default, sanitizes your `$PATH` for security reasons.  You can see the path by running:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'
```

Which will probably yield something like:

```
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

If you want to run something outside of those directories, you need to use a fully qualified path.  If *that* command tries to run something else using a relative path -- as in your example -- then you need to provide the `sudo` environment with a modified `$PATH`.  Like this:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH /home/timothythehuman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/passenger-memory-stats
```

This sets the `PATH` variable in the `sudo` environment.  The `env` command is useful for this sort of thing.

You can save yourself a little typing by doing this:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH `which passenger-memory-stats`
```

Comment: This works! It also reminds me of a command listed earlier in the tutorial. We were suppose to add `export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:/var/lib/gems/1.9/bin` to `bash.bashrc`. Perhaps I should add something like `:/var/lib/gems/2.0/bin` to the end of that? Note: I just tried, and to no effect. Any recommendations about hardcoding this into sudo's path?

Comment: I would actuall not recommend hardcoding this into sudo's path, since it's very application specific.  I would consider create a wrapper script that takes care of the environment setup, so you would just run `sudo wrapperscript`.